# How to transfer ERC-721 tokens using web3.js?

Tags: web3js, ethereumjs, erc-721, ethers.js, moralis

How to transfer ERC-721 tokens using web3.js? I am currently using moralis to transfer my ERC-721 tokens but is there other web3 providers other then moralis i have been trying to find then but so far there nothing :(

I tried moralis which goes like this :

```js
async function runcode() { 
  Moralis.enableWeb3();
  const options = {type: "erc721", receiver: '0xE1b1862d19D6cA6DB9aD3eC9Cd291f16939463fC', contractAddress: "0xc228fac3186d0a075967127b33710cd172b8d704", tokenId: 1}
  let result = await Moralis.transfer(options)
}
```

Comment: Please show us what you tried...

Comment: I tried moralis which goes like this :   async function runcode(){
        Moralis.enableWeb3()
        const options = {type: "erc721",  
                 receiver: '0xE1b1862d19D6cA6DB9aD3eC9Cd291f16939463fC',
                 contractAddress: "0xc228fac3186d0a075967127b33710cd172b8d704",
                 tokenId: 1}
let result = await Moralis.transfer(options)
}, but I can't find other web3 provider if you can help with this issue it could help me and my team.

Comment: you can use normal web3js/etherjs (with or without metamask) to interact with any contract. But you need then to take care of signing transactions, giving the input in the correct format, providing ABI .....etc. What moralis does is save you from all of that. here an example about web3js and contract interaction
https://medium.com/0xcode/interacting-with-smart-contracts-using-web3-js-34545a8a1ebd

Comment: Thanks you if I have further question I will notify.

Comment: Do I interact with the smart contract or just make Signed Transaction? @Majd TL

Comment: to interact with the contract and call a function in a contract you need to create a transaction (with correct data and format) and sign it (using a private key) and send it to the blockchain. You can use web3js or other libraries to do that. but if you are new then better to use easier libraries like Moralis

Comment: But what if am trying to interact with a specific function in my contract using web3?

Comment: How can I use web3.js without node.js?